# CSS Inline-block remove white space

Tags: css

I need a single container that's separated into three distinct areas with different backgrounds. I've got code that uses DIV to approximate this but the height and width is not right.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindg/1nqqtopo)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="square" id="square1">1</div>
        <div class="square" id="square2">2</div>
        <div class="square" id="square3">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm looking for is three "blocks" with different background colors that fill the width of the "container" (in this case a DIV), this looks like this:

[image: Blocks]

Comment: There are multiples solutions [here](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) ;)

Comment: Set the width of your container to 240px given 3*80px = 240px and you get the above result (http://jsfiddle.net/1nqqtopo/4/)

Answer (score 0):

simple answer add inline block to your container, and remove the width:

```
.container{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1nqqtopo/3/

Answer (score 0):

When you give `display: inline-block;` it generates spaces in-between them. Use the same code this way:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="square" id="square1">1</div><!--
     --><div class="square" id="square2">2</div><!--
     --><div class="square" id="square3">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```